# How to implement date query in luasql oci8?

Tags: lua, oci8, luasql

I am using oci8 driver of luasql to access Oracle database. All the queries are working fine. But if I try to implement a date query as:

```
conn:execute "select sysdate from dual"
```

It throws as error:

invalid type 12 #

I read it somewhere that the oci8 driver doesnot support date datatype. And some steps were mentioned to add support but that they didnot work.

So does anybody know how to integrate support for date in oci8 driver?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2005-11/msg00394.html

Comment: Convert date to string at Oracle side and receive a string at Lua side: `select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as result from dual`